# Is it a good idea to catch AssertionError in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit4

I have an object as the result of an API call and I want to assert the values of a member variable.

This value can be one of the two expected values depending on what the API call "sees" first and sets first. So if the assertion on one value fails, I want to assert for another value before declaring the test as a failure.

What is the best way of doing this? What I have right now is:

```
try {
    assertEquals("message", someObject.getValue1(), expectedValue1); 
} catch(AssertionError ae) {
    assertEquals("message", someObject.getValue1(), expectedValue2); 
}
```

I am just not sure if this is an acceptable practice. Please comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using exceptions as a sort of glorified goto statement is generally not a good practice. Or at least you will run into people in your career who take a dim view of using exceptions for program flow control.

How about:

```
Assert.assertTrue((someObject.getValue1().equals(expectedValue1) || (someObject.getValue2().equals(expectedValue2));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aquilon! In this case, my asserts are buried in a verification method that takes as parameters the properties of the object I need to assert for. So I can't really pass two expected values for the same property without changing the method's signature. So I am sticking to the original try...catch solution while noting your solution for future.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the purpose, automated functional testing or unit testing. I sometimes do this for the former:

```
try {
    assertTrue(boolean condition from earlier in test method to check);
}
catch(AssertionError uhOh) {
     Logger.err("condition X failed: detailed info msg"); // broken item #1

}

try {
    assertTrue(another condition in same method to check);
}
catch(AssertionError yuck) {
     Logger.err("condition X failed: detailed info msg"); // another broken item
     fail(); // now blow up as we've checked everything
}
```

Of course that's using logback Logger and JUnit's Assert.fail() which fails the test method. This way I know of all failures for this method rather than blowing up after the first. In my case, I'm testing a rich-content web app (dialogs and pages that take a lot of user input).

Downside of "fail-fast" (using no catches) is finding one problem, fixing it, running again and finding a new one ("rinse and repeat"), but if used for unit testing this is an asset due to the modularity of the tests (ideally you are only testing one aspect of an item per test).

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with Aquilon regarding this not being good practice.

However, can you use mocking or some other mechanism to "force" the API "see" one item before the other?  That way your tests can reflect the conditions that lead to one assertion being true in one test, and the other assertion being true in another test.